# Jquery each loop, find height of right side and add it to left side.

Tags: javascript, html, loops, variables

This might be an easy question for some people, but I can’t seem to get it right. I have some floated div’s. The ‘right side’ is taller than the ‘left side’. What I would like to do is, take the height of the ‘right side’ and add it to the ‘left side’.

I’m trying an each loop, but all i end up with is the last height of the ‘right side’. Anyone have any ideas?

```
     <style>
        .left, .right{
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 1em;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="left"/><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate aspernatur, dolore, totam alias beatae, modi distinctio voluptatum omnis blanditiis veniam quidem a itaque enim eos dolorum animi nobis nihil nemo!</p></div>

    <div class="right"/><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate aspernatur, dolore, totam alias beatae, modi distinctio voluptatum omnis blanditiis veniam quidem a itaque enim eos dolorum animi nobis nihil nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ipsum vero illo, earum nemo molestiae ratione, sunt tempore iusto ad dolorem minima atque debitis dolor recusandae dolorum id optio dolore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda quaerat numquam porro placeat aliquam sint fugit reprehenderit suscipit similique commodi minus magnam quod quis, cum nesciunt autem error, eum quasi.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="left"/><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate aspernatur, dolore, totam alias beatae, modi distinctio voluptatum omnis blanditiis veniam quidem a itaque enim eos dolorum animi nobis nihil nemo!</p></div>

    <div class="right"/><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate aspernatur, dolore, totam alias beatae, modi distinctio voluptatum omnis blanditiis veniam quidem a itaque enim eos dolorum animi nobis nihil nemo!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium ipsum vero illo, earum nemo molestiae ratione, sunt tempore iusto ad dolorem minima atque debitis dolor recusandae dolorum id optio dolore.</p>
    </div>        
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $left_side = $('.left');
    var $right_side = $('.right');
    var the_height = [];
    $('.container').each(function(index, val) {
        var elHeight = $(val).height();
        the_height.push(elHeight);
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of val inside loop..change it to $(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are interating over the amount of `$(".container")` instead of the `<div class="right">`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $left_side = $('.left');
    var $right_side = $('.right');
    var the_height = [];
    $('.right').each(function(index, val) {
        var elHeight = $(val).height();
        the_height.push(elHeight);
    });
});
```

If you are trying to make the left `<div class="left">` the same height as the right `<div class="right">` you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.right').each(function(index, val) {
        $(this).prev('.left').height($(this).height());
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $left_side = $('.left');
var $right_side = $('.right');
var the_height = [];
var divs=$(".container").children();
$(divs).each(function(index,val){
   the_height.push($(this).height())
})
})
```

this shuld also work

Answer (score 0):

`$('.container')` is just one div. I think you want to loop through the children the `.container`. This is one of the ways you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $left_side = $('.left');
    var $right_side = $('.right');
    var the_height = [];
    $('.container').children().each(function(index, val) {
        var elHeight = $(val).height();
        the_height.push(elHeight);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from what you said you want to accomplish, I'd say the code is not going to work properly. Here's a code that adds the right height to the left one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').each(function() {
        var right_height = $(this).children("div.right").height();
        var left_height = $(this).children("div.left").height();
        $(this).children("div.left").height(right_height + left_height)
    });
});
```

Also, all your divs are wrong! You're not supposed to close them in the opening tag:

```
<div class="left"/>
```

You have to remove the slash:

```
<div class="left">
```